# how to remove PTS gap within a file when transcoding with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, pts

i have a video which is from rtmp streaming.

Since the broadcasting is on and off frequently,

the archived file has PTS like below

(assume that this is sec)

0--10--20--30--40 120--130--140

there's discontinuity between 40 and 120 sec.

duration of this file must be 60sec since there's 80sec gap between 40~120.

but when i transcoded this file, final duration became 140sec with 80sec of pausing parts.

how can i transcode this file without "not existing" 80 sec so that output file became 60sec without redundant pausing 80 sec.

i tried "+getpts" or "+igndts" options but they don't work at all.

Answer (score 4):

Use the setpts filter.

```
ffmpeg -i in.flv -vf setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB out.mp4
```

If there's audio as well, add `-af asetpts=N/SR/TB`.

Comment: If there's audio too, i think there must be syncing problem between audio and video. is there any other options to save sync between audio and video?

Comment: If the audio PTS doesn't have corresponding discontinuities, then the audio will have to trimmed manually. If there's silence during the video freezes, then the [silenceremove](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silenceremove) filter may work.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. i'm gonna figure out if there's any better way to trim parts